# How to iterate correctly through a list of data frame columns with a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I have a dataframe "old_df" and I would like to refer to its columns with "i" in a for loop and do some operations (the operation below is only an example).

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3)
v2 <- c(4,5,6)
old_df = data.frame(Price=v1, Value=v2)

colnames = c("Price", "Value")
new_df = data.frame(Price=numeric(), 
                 Value=numeric()) 

for (i in colnames) {
    new_df$i <- old_df$i
}
```

However referencing this way (`old_df$i`) does not work. Writing `old_df$"Price"` into the console gives back the correct column, writing `i` gives back label `"Price"`, however `old_df$i` gives back `NULL`. What is the problem here?

Comment: `$` isn't evaluating its RHS, this was discussed many times on SO, Google it up.

Comment: Terms to try searching for are 'access column dataframe R'...

Comment: Could you give a link to one of those discussions? I haven't found anything that would solve the problem.